# The integral of the axial current conservation law

Tags: conservation-laws, gauge-theory

In the section 19.1 "The Axial Current in Two Dimensions" of  Peskin & Shroeder.
On page 657,

> In free fermion theory, the integral of the axial current conservation law gives
>   $$ \int d^2x\,  \partial_{\mu}j^{\,\mu 5} =N_R -N_L \quad (=0) \tag{19.30} $$

What's this?
If (19.30) is correct,  it follows that in the ordinary four-dimensional case,

\begin{cases}
\displaystyle N_R=\int d^4x \, \partial_{\mu} \bar{\psi} \gamma^{\mu}\left(\frac{1+\gamma^5}{2}\right)\psi =\int d^4x \, \partial_{\mu}j_R^{\,\mu}, \\
\displaystyle
N_L=\int d^4x \, \partial_{\mu} \bar{\psi} \gamma^{\mu}\left(\frac{1-\gamma^5}{2}\right)\psi =\int d^4x \, \partial_{\mu}j_L^{\,\mu}, \\
\displaystyle
N=\int d^4 \, \partial_{\mu} \bar{\psi} \gamma^{\mu}\psi = \int d^4x \, \partial_{\mu}j^{\,\mu}. 
\end{cases}

These look weird to me.

Comment: What looks weird to You?

Comment: Is the definition of $N_R,\,N_L\text{ and }N $ rirght?

Comment: No, these definitions You used are the time derivatives of $N_{L/R},N$ under an assumption that the spatial cirrents vanishes at infinity.

Answer (score 1):

One correcrion: these definitions are the time integrals over the time derivatives of the quantities 
$$
N(t)=\int d^{3}\mathbf r J^{0}(\mathbf r, t)
$$ 
under an assumption that the spatial currents vanishes at infinity, 
$$
\int d^{4}\mathbf r \nabla \cdot \mathbf J =\oint d\mathbf S \cdot \mathbf J \to 0
$$ 
With these assumptions, the integral 
$$
\int d^{4}x \partial_{\mu}J^{\mu} = \int \limits_{t_{0}}^{t_{1}} dt \frac{dN}{dt}
$$
of a time derivative of $N$ is reduced to the values of $N$ at the boundaries $t_1, t_0$ of the integration, namely, 
$$
N(t_{1})-N(t_0) = \Delta N
$$

Comment: Thank you so much! I've summarized the content inspired by you as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

In four dimensions, 
The correct definition of $N_R ,\,N_L \, \text{and}\, N$ is
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle 
N_R=\int d^3 \mathbf{x} \, \bar{\psi} \gamma^{0}P_R \psi =\int d^3 \mathbf{x} \, \bar{\psi} \gamma^{0}\left(\frac{1+\gamma^5}{2}\right)\psi =\int d^3 \mathbf{x} \, j_R^{\,0}\,, \\
\displaystyle 
N_L=\int d^3 \mathbf{x} \, \bar{\psi} \gamma^{0}P_L \psi =\int d^3 \mathbf{x} \, \bar{\psi} \gamma^{0}\left(\frac{1-\gamma^5}{2}\right)\psi =\int d^3 \mathbf{x} \, j_L^{\,0}\,, \\
\displaystyle 
N=\int d^3 \mathbf{x} \, \bar{\psi} \gamma^{0}\psi = \int d^3 \mathbf{x} \, j^{\,0}\,. 
\end{cases}
$N$ is the Noether charge $Q$ associated with the vector current conservation law.
Let $Q^5$ be the Noether charge associated with the axial current conservation law.
$$ Q^5= \int d^3 \mathbf{x} \, j^{\,05} =\int d^3 \mathbf{x} \, \bar{\psi} \gamma^{0}\gamma^{5}\psi = \int d^3 \mathbf{x} \,\left( \bar{\psi} \gamma^{0}P_R\psi - \, \bar{\psi} \gamma^{0}P_L\psi \right) =N_R-N_L $$
$$ \partial_0 Q^5=\partial_0 N_R - \partial_0 N_L= \int d^3 \mathbf{x} \, \partial_0 \bar{\psi} \gamma^{0}\gamma^{5}\psi = \int d^3 \mathbf{x} \, \partial_0 j^{\,05} = \int d^3 \mathbf{x} \, \partial_{\mu} j^{\,\mu 5}=0 $$
This is under an assumption that the spatial axial currents vanishes at infinity.
$$ \int d^3 \mathbf{x} \,\partial_i j^{\,i5} =\oint d\mathbf S \cdot \mathbf j^5 \to 0 $$
$$ \therefore \Delta N_R - \Delta N_L =0 = \int d^4 x \, \partial_0 \bar{\psi} \gamma^{0}\gamma^{5}\psi  = \int d^4 x \, \partial_{\mu} j^{\,\mu 5} $$

In two dimensions,
$$ Q^5= \int d x^1 \, \bar{\psi} \gamma^{0}\gamma^{5}\psi = \int d x^1 \,\left( \bar{\psi} \gamma^{0}P_R\psi - \bar{\psi} \gamma^{0}P_L\psi \right) =N_R-N_L $$
$$ \partial_0 Q^5=\partial_0 N_R - \partial_0 N_L= \int d x^1 \, \partial_0 \bar{\psi} \gamma^{0}\gamma^{5}\psi = \int d x^1 \,\partial_0 j^{\,05}=\int d x^1 \,\partial_{\mu} j^{\,\mu 5} =0 $$

Here the authors assume the spatial axial current vnishes at infinity.
$$ \int dx^1 \, \partial_1 j^{\,15} =\left[ j^{\,15}\right]_{-\infty}^{\infty} \to 0 $$

(19.30) should be replaced by
$$ \int d^2x\,  \partial_{\mu}j^{\,\mu 5} =\Delta N_R -\Delta N_L =0 .\tag{19.30} $$
So the sentence just below (19.30)

> This relation implies that the difference in the number of right-moving and left-moving fermions cannot be changed in any possible process.

should be replaced by

> This relation implies that the difference in the variation of right-moving and left-moving fermion numbers cannot be changed in any possible process.

The LHS of (19.39) should be also
$$ \Delta N_R -\Delta N_L .$$

Comment: "This is under an assumption that the spatial axial currents vanishes at infinity."

It might be worth pointing out that in this specific example, the assumption is that *the system has a finite length $L$, with periodic boundary conditions*.